# How can I make a list of dictionaries according to the Cartesian product of values in a source dictionary ("explode" the dictionary)?

Tags: python, dictionary, cartesian-product

Given a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    'Color': ['Red', 'Yellow'],
    'Size': ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
}
```

How can I create a list of dictionaries that combines the various values of the first dictionary's keys? What I want is:

```
[
    {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Small'},
    {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Medium'},
    {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Large'},
    {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Small'},
    {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Medium'},
    {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Large'}
]
```

Comment: This would be a good question if you showed us what you've tried.

Comment: I'd say this is a good question in any case because it's not easy to come up with the right concept here.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you want the Cartesian product, not a permutation, in which case [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can help:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> d = {'Color': ['Red', 'Yellow'], 'Size': ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']}
>>> [dict(zip(d, v)) for v in product(*d.values())]
[{'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Small'}, {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Medium'}, {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Large'}, {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Small'}, {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Medium'}, {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Large'}]
```

Comment: +1. Good to know that Python iterates over the dictionary items in the same, reproducible order, both for the `zip()` and the `.values()`!

Comment: @TimPietzcker: yes, this property is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and can be relied on.  The order itself is arbitrary, but no compliant Python implementation can violate the guarantee that if you don't modify `d`, `d.keys()` (here `d`) and `d.values()` have to match.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.

Comment: I think since python 3.7 the dict order is also not arbitrary anymore! See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872498/will-ordereddict-become-redundant-in-python-3-7)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain that result doing this:

```
x={'Color': ['Red', 'Yellow'], 'Size': ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']}
keys=x.keys()
values=x.values()

matrix=[]
for i in range(len(keys)):
     cur_list=[]
     for j in range(len(values[i])):
             cur_list.append({keys[i]: values[i][j]})
     matrix.append(cur_list)

y=[]
for i in matrix[0]:
     for j in matrix[1]:
             y.append(dict(i.items() + j.items()))

print y
```

result:

```
[{'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Small'}, {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Medium'}, {'Color': 'Red', 'Size': 'Large'}, {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Small'}, {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Medium'}, {'Color': 'Yellow', 'Size': 'Large'}]
```