# Get list of all possible dict configs in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have dict that describes possible config values, e.g.

```
{'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4,5]}
```

I want to generate list of all acceptable configs, e.g.

```
[{'a':1, 'b':3},
 {'a':1, 'b':4},
 {'a':1, 'b':5},
 {'a':2, 'b':3},
 {'a':2, 'b':4},
 {'a':1, 'b':5}]
```

I've looked through the docs and SO and it certainly seems to involve `itertools.product`, but I can't get it without a nested for loop.

Comment: check last one it should be `{'a':2, 'b':5}`right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a nested `for` loop here:

```
from itertools import product
[dict(zip(d.keys(), combo)) for combo in product(*d.values())]
```

`product(*d.values())` produces your required value combinations, and `dict(zip(d.keys(), combo))` recombines each combination with the keys again.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> d = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4,5]} 
>>> list(product(*d.values()))
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
>>> [dict(zip(d.keys(), combo)) for combo in product(*d.values())]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 5},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 5}]
```

Comment: It might be worth showing the intermediate step of `product(*d.values())` to make it more obvious why this works.

Comment: Hmmph.  I was going to close as a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211568/combine-python-dictionary-permutations-into-list-of-dictionaries) but yours is more explanatory and this question has a better title.

Comment: @DSM: it doesn't seem quite fair that close as a dupe in the other direction *either*. Closing this one as a dupe is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
>>> dt={'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4,5]} 
>>> [{'a':i,'b':j} for i in dt['a'] for j in dt['b']]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}]
```