# Generate a list of dictionaries representing all combinations of the values for each key

Tags: python

Having the following dictionary:

```
d = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': [True, False]
}
```

How can I generate a list of dictionaries representing all combinations of the values for each key? The output should be like this:

```
combinations = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': True},
  {'a': 2, 'b': True},
  {'a': 3, 'b': True},
  {'a': 1, 'b': False},
  {'a': 2, 'b': False},
  {'a': 3, 'b': False}
]
```

This should work with an arbitrary number of keys and an arbitrary length of values in the dictionary. We can assume that the values are always a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using `itertools`:

```
[dict(zip(d, values)) for values in itertools.product(*d.values())]
```

Comment: If you're going to ask and self-answer (which is fine!) you should make sure to check for dups.  This question is a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724860/get-list-of-all-possible-dict-configs-in-python) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211568/combine-python-dictionary-permutations-into-list-of-dictionaries) and probably others too.

Comment: @DSM: you are right. I always search for duplicates (because before having an answer, I had the question, so I was also interested in finding a solution), but didn't find anything. I also always check the "possible duplicates" list when asking a question, but no real duplicates were displayed in there. I guess sometimes it is not so easy to find actual duplicates (it seems YusufX couldn't find the duplicate either before asking the same question). Anyway, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DSM: marked as duplicate. ;-)