# Code works well, but doesn't seem very Pythonic - How can I improve this dictionary creation and the creation of combinations from that dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got two dictionaries which I turn in to a dictionary of lists using the code below. It works, but it seems like non-Pythonic way to do it. Basically, it's ugly and will need to be updated if either of my other dictionaries gets updated.

```
KeyWeight = {x: MCNWeight[AttributeName[x]] for x in AttributeName.keys()}

list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
list4 = []
list5 = []
list6 = []
list7 = []
list8 = []
list9 = []

for x, y in KeyWeight.iteritems():
if y == 1:
    list1.append(x)
elif y == 2:
    list2.append(x)
elif y == 3:
    list3.append(x)
elif y == 4:
    list4.append(x)
elif y == 5:
    list5.append(x)
elif y == 6:
    list6.append(x)
elif y == 7:
    list7.append(x)
elif y == 8:
    list8.append(x)
elif y == 9:
    list9.append(x)

KeyWeight = {1: list1, 2: list2, 3: list3, 4: list4, 5: list5, 6: list6, 7: list7, 8: list8, 9: list9}
```

After that, I have a pretty gross nested for loop that creates all possible combinations of that dictionary (shown below). It gives the results I'm looking for and runs quickly, but I have the nagging feeling that there's a better way to do it.

Thank you very much for any help you're able to offer!

```
MasterMCN = []
MCNs = None


for each1 in KeyWeight[1]:
    MCNs = each1
    for each2 in KeyWeight[2]:
        MCNs2 = MCNs + '-' + each2
        for each3 in KeyWeight[3]:
            MCNs3 = MCNs2 + '-' + each3
            for each4 in KeyWeight[4]:
                MCNs4 = MCNs3 + '-' + each4
                for each5 in KeyWeight[5]:
                    MCNs5 = MCNs4 + '-' + each5
                    for each6 in KeyWeight[6]:
                        MCNs6 = MCNs5 + '-' + each6
                        for each7 in KeyWeight[7]:
                            MCNs7 = MCNs6 + '-' + each7
                            for each8 in KeyWeight[8]:
                                MCNs8 = MCNs7 + '-' + each8
                                for each9 in KeyWeight[9]:
                                    MCNs9 = MCNs8 + '-' + each9
                                    MasterMCN.append(MCNs9)
```

EDIT:
Thanks to Moses' answer, I've been able to get rid of the nasty for loop. The better version is below.

```
for weight in sorted(KeyWeight.keys()):
    if not MasterMCN:
        MasterMCN = KeyWeight[weight]
    else:
        iter_prod = itertools.product(MasterMCN, KeyWeight[weight])
        MasterMCN = ['-'.join(x) for x in iter_prod]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to preallocate those lists, use a `defaultdict` with `list` as values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in KeyWeight.iteritems():
   d[y].append(x)
KeyWeight = d
```

To create combinations from the list values you can simply use `itertools.combinations`. You can use this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478317/3125566) that uses `itertools.product` and preserves key-value ordering as a guide.

Comment: Beautiful and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply using a list of list, with y as index ?